# AndroidのANRとクラッシュの対応方法について

Tags: android

個人の趣味としてAndroidアプリの開発をしています。
ブラウザアプリを配信しているのですが、「ANRとクラッシュ」で報告される下記のエラーについて、どのように対応すべきか理解ができません。
このようなAndroid側のクラスで発生しているエラーについてどのように対応をすすめるべきか、ヒントだけでもよいので助言をいただけると大変助かります。

ちなみに自身で毎日使用してもエラーが特に発生していないので、イレギュラーなケースで発生するものと思われます。
OSはAndroid5〜7まで報告があり、特に特定のOSや端末に集中しているわけではないようです。

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$SendWindowContentChangedAccessibilityEvent.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7154)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1):

Frameworkの不具合だと思います。
↓がFixコミットです(8.0以降に入っています)。

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/478cb9746a57ba8f5a596ef941c936faa7c74784

TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGEDというAccessibilityEventを発行する処理が、マルチスレッドでコールされた場合に該当のエラーが発生するケースがありそうです。

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED

TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGEDはViewの追加や削除、サイズ変更等があった際に発生するイベントです。